# Irreducible components of a cyclic extension over $ \mathbb{Q} $

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}$Let $ L $ be a cyclic Galois extension of $ \mathbb{Q} $ of degree $ 6 $. So $ G = \Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}) $ is a cyclic group of order $ 6 $. Then we have a homomorphism $ \phi : G \rightarrow \GL (L) $ defined by  $ \phi(\sigma)(g) = \sigma(g) $  for all $ \sigma \in G $. Thus by representation theory we can consider $ L $ as a $\mathbb{Q}G $ module. Then $ L $ can be  written as a direct-sum decomposition of $ r $ distinct  irreducible  submodules. What is the value of $ r $? And what are the irreducible components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [normal basis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_basis#Group_representation_point_of_view), $L$ is the regular representation of $G$, i.e., $r = 6$ and the components are the $6$ distinct characters of $G$.

EDIT:  As pointed out in the comments, particularly by [@FrançoisBrunault](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411960/irreducible-components-of-a-cyclic-extension-over-mathbbq/411962#comment1055624_411962), that is $L \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb C$ as a $\mathbb C[G]$-module; $L$ itself as a $\mathbb Q[G]$-module has $4$ summands, corresponding to the trivial and sign characters, and the two other pairs of complex conjugate characters.

Comment: I don't think that there will be 6 summands over ${\mathbb Q}$; it seems that $r=4$ in this case since $x^6-1$ decomposes into 4 irreducible factors over ${\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: @VictorOstrik, I'm not sure I follow why the number of irreducible factors of $x^6 - 1$ controls the number of summands in a decomposition of a cyclic extension of degree $6$.

Comment: The group algebra $\mathbb{Q}G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1) \times \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$ and this is the decomposition as a $G$-module for the left multiplication by $G$. Over $\mathbb{C}$ your answer is correct of course.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault, ah, yes, I see, I was indeed unthinkingly working with the $\mathbb C$-algebra.